# How do I get my bake to match my material node output

Tags: materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

I have been banging my head on this for a few hours now, and would love any help. I am using a ManuelBastioni Lab character that really only uses cycles. Since I am using blender render for my project I really need to simplify everything so that it works for my game. ManuelBastioni gives you a bunch of textures to work with and after studying his cycles material tree I made my own in blender render that seemed to do exactly what I wanted.

[image: My Node Tree]

I assigned my new blender internal material to the whole character and deleted all the other nodes. I made a new material that houses the texture image to be baked on and set my bake to texture mode. However, the bake looks like it is not taking consideration the UV map and it looks like a smushed mess. What am I doing wrong??

[image: My Texture Bake]

Comment: Try to add Geometry node, it has UV output that can be connected to the textures.

Comment: :D So simple and yet so effective! Thank you so much! That worked!

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly.
The solution was to add a geometry node with the UV map to each texture node. Thanks Denis!